# Could not find the correct Provider

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, flutter-provider

I'm new to using flutter and i was trying to implement a covid 19 tracker of cases in the world and i got this error when creating a custom widget to display number of cases , can anyone help me figure out the solution to this exactly as i have been trying  to fix it for hours now.
This is the exception caught by the widgets library:
Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this NewCasesCard Widget

To fix, please:

- Ensure the Provider is an ancestor to this NewCasesCard Widget
- Provide types to Provider
- Provide types to Consumer
- Provide types to Provider.of()
- Ensure the correct `context` is being used.

If none of these solutions work, please file a bug at:
https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:stay_safe/Providers/AppBrain.dart';
import 'package:stay_safe/utils/theme.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class NewCasesCard extends StatelessWidget {



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return getCard(context);
  }
  Widget getCard(context){
      if (Provider.of<AppBrain>(context).isloading2)
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Center(
          child: SpinKitPumpingHeart(color: AppTheme().kcolors[0],),
        ),
      );
      else {
        final countryInfo = Provider.of<AppBrain>(context).countryStats['countrydata'][0];
return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Card(
        elevation: 0.5,
              color: Colors.white70,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text('New Cases Today',style: GoogleFonts.cabin(fontSize: 25),),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 8,),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[
                StatIcon(countryInfo['total_active_cases'], 'Active', AppTheme().kcolors[0]),
                StatIcon(countryInfo['total_new_cases_today'], 'New Cases', AppTheme().kcolors[2]),
                StatIcon(countryInfo['total_new_deaths_today'], 'Deaths', AppTheme().kcolors[1])
              ],),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
      }
  }
}
Widget StatIcon(int count,String type,Color color){
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
    Text(count.toString(),style: GoogleFonts.cabin(color: color,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 20),),
    Text(type,style: GoogleFonts.cabin(color: color,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 20),),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: did you navigated from where you initialised?

Comment: sorry i didnt understand ur question

Comment: i mean you are you navigating from one screen to another screen then are you facing this issue ?

Comment: Noo im just getting it(red error screen) when i go to the screen that includes this widget

Comment: can you add screen shot?

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks like you have created the `AppBrain` provider in a different part of your widget tree to `NewCasesCard`, so when `NewCasesCard` attempts to find the provider by searching the tree it cannot. You need to make sure that the `AppBrain` provider is above `NewCasesCard` somewhere in the widget tree. So for example in the screen that includes this widget you could have:

```dart
class NewCasesScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<AppBrain>(
      create: (_) => AppBrain(),
        child: Scaffold(
          body: ListView(
            children: [
              NewCasesCard(),
              ...
            ]
        ),
      ),
    ); 
  }
```

Alternatively you could initialise the provider at the top of your app since, from the name, it looks like it is used throughout. For this you could utilise the `MultiProvider` and have:
(Example taken from the [package readme](https://pub.dev/packages/provider#-readme-tab-))

```dart
void main {
  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      Provider<AppBrain>(create: (_) => AppBrain()),
      Provider<SomethingElse>(create: (_) => SomethingElse()),
    ],
    child: MaterialApp(...),
   ));
}
```

This way you can be sure that the provider will always be found.